# Add link tag to each row in table and open modal

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

Below is my HTML file with my markup with table populated from JSON.

Trying to add an link tag (a href="#") on each row, the link should have onClick event to open modal with its object content. its object name, surname & age

I created var link = document.createElement("a"), but not sure how o append and than open modal with the object row data.

```js
const data = [
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "John",
  "surname": "Doe",
  "age":45,
  "mobile": "555-555-9876",
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Mary",
  "surname": "Andrew",
  "age": 31,
  "mobile": "555-555-3524",
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Joe",
  "surname": "White",
  "age": 22,
  "mobile": "555-5555-2453",
},
]
function getUsers(data) {
var users = data;

  var table = document.getElementById("table");

  var count = 0; 

  for(use in users){ 

      var row = table.insertRow(count);

      console.log("row : ", row)

      var link = document.createElement("a");
      link.setAttribute("onclick", function() {});
      link.className = "class";
      var linkText = document.createTextNode("link");
      link.appendChild(linkText);
         // stuck here

      row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = users[count].id;
      row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = users[count].name;
      row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = users[count].mobile;  

      count++;
  }
}

window.onload = getUsers(data);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Users</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Users</h1>
    <div>
    <table >
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">name</th>
            <th scope="col">mobile</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="table">
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./app.js"></script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't really need to use JS Fiddle, you can add HTML/CSS/JS snippets to your post using the button to the right of the "Insert <img>" button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you are already doing in your code, you can append `link` to an element. In the code below I've added the link to the first cell in each row (`row.insertCell(0).appendChild(link);`) and filled it before doing so with the ID (`link.innerHTML = users[i].id;`).

Also if you want to create an eventListener like `onClick` after the page has loaded you'll have to explicitly create one by using `.addEventListener` instead of creating an onClick-attribute. (`link.addEventListener("click", function() { ... });`)

A few other small things as well:

- You can name your variables in the function declaration directly `getUsers(users)` (no need for `var users = data;`)
- You can also create an iterating variable inside the loop declaration `for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {`. This way you only need one line. (I've replaced `count` with `i`).

With all these changes your code will look like it does below. All that is left is to create the modal. You can pass the data into it where I've put the `alert()` message. If you need help with that check out some online resources like [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp).

```
// Omitted the data (unchanged)

function getUsers(users) {
  var table = document.getElementById("table");

  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    var row = table.insertRow(i);

    console.log("row : ", row)

    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.setAttribute('href', '#')
    link.addEventListener("click", function() {
      alert('Open modal here!');
    });
    link.className = "class";
    link.innerHTML = users[i].id;

    row.insertCell(0).appendChild(link);
    row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = users[i].name;
    row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = users[i].mobile;  

    row.firstChild.appendChild(link);
  }
}

window.onload = getUsers(data);
```